# force download file from s3 using php

Tags: php, amazon-s3, download

I want to download the file directly from s3 to user machine. So I have googled and came up with something like this. But this is not working.

```
$objInfo = $s3->getObjectInfo('bucket', 'filename.mp3');
$obj = $s3->getObject('bucket', 'filename.mp3');

header('Content-type: ' . $objInfo['type']);
echo $obj->body;
```

How to force download file not based on URL from s3.

Comment: error ? or is it just outputs binary stream as text ? if so, try 
header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");

Comment: thanx for your reply.. It doesnt producing error.. Browser keeps on loading and suddenly gets hang and then crashes.. If i print the objinfo value everything looks fine..

Answer (score 1):

try adding

```
Content-Disposition: attachment
```

to the header, optionally you can also specify the filename for the file being downloaded with

```
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=somefile.ext
```